# New JS SDK with OAuth 2.0 saving subdomain in fbsr_ cookie?

Tags: javascript, facebook, cookies, oauth

EDIT: This bug was logged, and confirmed as a [Facebook bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/256155664428653?browse=search_4e843e6d89a232275456793). It has now been fixed!

---

---

I am testing my updates to move onto the new JS SDK. My app runs across multiple subdomains of my domain. On the old JDK, I was calling something like this:

```
FB.init({
    appId: [APP_ID],
    status: false,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true
});
FB.login();
```

On the new JDK, it looks like this:

```
FB.init({
    appId: [APP_ID],
    status: false,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    oauth:true
});
FB.login();
```

Using a cookie manager FF add on, you can see that the old version would set a cookie on mydomain.com, but the new one sets it to www.mydomain.com - meaning my other subdomain cannot access the cookie.

To clarify: The problem is that I cannot use the facebook cookie on different subdomains, and also if I log them in on every subdomain, I have to log them out from every subdomain too

Comment: I think you should file a bug for this... http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: You should really consider reporting this as a bug, as Tim suggested. I can confirm this new behaviour and, even if it doesn't affect any of my apps directly, it's at least an undocumented change.

Comment: Logged as a bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/256155664428653?browse=search_4e843e6d89a232275456793

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: The bug has been updated by Facebook to 'Fixed'. Hooray!

This is a facebook bug and has been logged, reproduced and accepted as high priority here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/256155664428653?browse=search_4e843e6d89a232275456793

Comment: Did you ever have any luck with working around this? I have the same problem.

Comment: I am doing something messy to get around it. Instead of using the cookie, i sent the auth response sig and contents via ajax to my server which verifies them and uses a server side session.

Answer (score 15):

If you set oauth to true when calling FB.init() via the Javascript API, you now get an fbsr_APP_ID cookie instead of a fbs_APP_ID cookie (notice the "r"). It contains a signed request and part of the oauth migration.

If you use the PHP SDK, it should take care of the change.

However, the docs for websites do not appear to be updated with a new get_facebook_cookie() function: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/

It still uses the old cookie format. You can find how to parse a signed request here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Then, you need to turn the "code" parameter in the cookie into an access_token via the docs here:
developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ (no http:// because of StackOverflow spam prevention)

I dug around in the source of the new PHP SDK a little bit to figure this out since all of the documentation does not appear to be updated.

The full code that I am using is a combination of the above with a little extra modifications to work with the old or new cookie format is below. The new get_facebook_cookie() function does return a few additional array elements (algorithm, code, issued_at, user_id) and a few array elements are no longer set (base_domain, secret, session_key, sig). The primary parameters most people are looking for are most likely set though (uid, access_token, and expires)

```
function get_facebook_cookie($app_id, $app_secret) {
    if ($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id] != '') {
        return get_new_facebook_cookie($app_id, $app_secret);
    } else {
        return get_old_facebook_cookie($app_id, $app_secret);
    }
}

function get_old_facebook_cookie($app_id, $app_secret) {
    $args = array();
    parse_str(trim($_COOKIE['fbs_' . $app_id], '\\"'), $args);
    ksort($args);
    $payload = '';
    foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
        if ($key != 'sig') {
            $payload .= $key . '=' . $value;
        }
    }
    if (md5($payload . $app_secret) != $args['sig']) {
        return array();
    }
    return $args;   
}

function get_new_facebook_cookie($app_id, $app_secret) {
    $signed_request = parse_signed_request($_COOKIE['fbsr_' . $app_id], $app_secret);
    // $signed_request should now have most of the old elements
    $signed_request[uid] = $signed_request[user_id]; // for compatibility 
    if (!is_null($signed_request)) {
        // the cookie is valid/signed correctly
        // lets change "code" into an "access_token"
        $access_token_response = file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=$app_id&redirect_uri=&client_secret=$app_secret&code=$signed_request[code]");
        parse_str($access_token_response);
        $signed_request[access_token] = $access_token;
        $signed_request[expires] = time() + $expires;
    }
    return $signed_request;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I am happy with the new behaviour using oauth:true, but my question is regarding the host/subdomain issue rather than how to use the new cookie. The cookie is being set with a host of www.domain.com but i need to read it on the server at subdomain.domain.com and it is not available here. The old cookie had a domain of domain.com rather than a host of www.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

1) Check your App. domain in settings is set as mydomain.com and not www.mydomain.com
2) Use channel file and url in init:

```
FB.init({  
appId : [APP_ID],  
status : false,  
cookie : true,  
xfbml : true,
channelUrl : document.location.protocol + "//domain.com/xd_receiver.html",  
oauth : true
});
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init/

hope this helps

Comment: definately is using mydomain.com in the settings. I have tried to use the channelurl in the past but never had much luck. I will try again and see how it goes. Thank you

Comment: I tried adding a channelUrl and the cookie still has a host specifying the subdomain :(

Answer (score 0):

check out this
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/`<appid>`/summary

look at the App Domain:  part of "Basic Info:"
if you specify "www.example.com"  than it will only work for www.example.com.  If you use "example.com"  it will treat it as *.example.com  and work for all subdomains

Comment: Hi, I already have it set with mydomain.com and this is still an issue.

Comment: consider changing php_value session.cookie_domain .domain.com in your php.ini file    note the leading "." in front of your root domain.   I haven't tested this, but it's a path of potential success.  let me know how it goes
http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain